# why docker container consume huge CPU load average

Tags: rhel, docker, cpu, load-average, docker-compose

I want to discuss about strange behavior on our rhel 7.6 server

We installed Kafka exporter with container on the server – kafka-01 machine ( total CPU on machine are 12 )

The following `yml` file described the Kafka exporter container  configuration

```
more  docker.kafka-exporter.yml
---
version: '2.4'
services:
  kafka-exporter:
    mem_limit: "612m"
    image: kafka-exporter:v1.2.0
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    container_name: kafka-exporter
    command: ["--kafka.server=kafka01.sys65.com:6667"]ump 
    ports:
      - 9308:9308
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "15m"
        max-file: "1"
```

so when we start the container with `dockr-compose` ,  as `docker-compose -f docker.kafka-exporter.yml  up -d`

we notices that CPU load average jump from `~2-3` to `30-40` after 1-2 hours

and only restart of machine return the normal CPU load average to normal ( around `1 - 2` )  , but again CPU jump each time we start the docker compose , ( even stopping the docker compose not decrease the CPU load average  )

can someone gives some hint what could be the reason for that strange behavior ?

regarding our case is it useful to consider to install the https://github.com/draios/sysdig , for investigation ?

Notes:

We verified the CPU load avrg from `uptime` linux command

*sometimes machine became **freeze** or **HANG** so we cant access the machine , and only reboot help to return machine again to normal*

Comment: Why do you believe this is a docker issue and not an issue with the kafka-exporter? I can't find `kafka-exporter:v1.2.0` on docker-hub so it's not clear precisely what image you're trying to run.  I'm guessing this is a java process so you may want to try increasing the memory limit as java's memory manager can consume a lot of CPU when it gets low on spare RAM.

Comment: You may also like to try adding a CPU limit on the container to protect the machine from freezing.

Comment: can you please show me how to add CPU limit on the container in my docker.kafka-exporter.yml file?

Comment: that's a matter for google. There's an artical here showing it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-memory-limit) You can also read the )Note that it's different depending on the `version` you declared.  https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-memory-limit You can also read the manual on `cpus` [for version 2](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-memory-limit) and [for version 3](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/deploy.md#cpus)